# HE-AAC Conversion

Tags: audio, mp3, converters, aac

guys!

I've been asked at work to prepare a large audio library for tests, which includes different files of HE-AACv1 & HE-AACv2. To be specific, all sample rates from 8000 up to 48000 and bit rates from 8 bit to 32 bit. But I've been digging the internet for a while and can't find the exact information. Is it even possible to make HE-AAC with 8KHz sample rate? And are there any tools that allow to directly set this specific values (bit rate and sample rate)? I've tried adobe audition, audacity and a bunch of something I found on google, but neither gives me opportunities that I need, or it's just me being dumb.

Please, if you know the way to create a HE-AACv1 and v2 from for example mp3 or wav, tell me how to do it, I would be very grateful.

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe Audition can definitely create all WAVs that you need, look under "Edit->Convert sample type". You should first create your wav files, and then use some encoder to transcode to AAC.